# Associate contact entity to multiple entities using Web API- Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-online

I am needing to associate contacts entity to multiple studios(studios is a custom entity). I am using a lookup field in contacts entity, `contact.studioid` to do the same.

I am able to associate initially then replace Studio associations using Web API using this 
`contact["studioid_odata.bind"] = "/studios(GUID)"` line in my Web API JSON body which works well to replace the studio.

I would like to know how to associate a new studio to the contact on each call, without replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

If entity is custom then it will have some prefix on the start like "new_". Anyway my recommendation is to use CRMRestBuilder to build your request - https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder/releases/tag/2.6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

If the Contact has a `studioid` then your relationship is the wrong way round as this means that **a Contact can only have a single studio**

You need to create another relationship between the `contact` and `studio` entities. Depending on your requirements, this can be (from the Contact record) a

- A `1:N` Relationship; or
- An `N:N` Relationship